# ¿Que librería timer usar en Arduino para manejar servomotor con timer?

Tags: arduino

¿Cómo uso un timer para que al cabo de ese tiempo abra un servomotor y lo cierre con un delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es controlar el tiempo lo puedes hacer de dos maneras. Con una librería como TimeLib.h sin utilizar RTC. El inconveniente es que cuando se apaga Arduino pierdes sincronización.

Si utilizas un RTC (Real Time Clock) evitas perder esa sincronización cuando se apague la placa. En este caso el DS3231 o el DS3107 te pueden servir. Esto junto con la librería RTClib.h de Adafruit.

Puedes ver un tutorial completo sobre esto en https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/reloj-con-arduino-rtc/